# Как вывести данные на консоль в csv формате?

Tags: python, csv

Задача такая, нужно сгенерировать  фейковые данные и вывести их в консоль используя уже готовый csv-форматер. Сгенерировать данные несложно, но как вывести их в консоль, вот это непонятно. Те варианты, которые пытался реализовать, выдавали ошибку, да и в принципе были несуразны, может кто-то знает решение или направление в котором двигаться?

```
from mimesis import Person, Address
from random import randint
import csv
import sys
import time

def generate_users(usersNum, region):
    myFile = open('example2.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
    data = []
    if region == "uk":
        country = "Укр"
    elif region == "ru":
        country = "Рф"
    elif region == "en":
        country = "US"

    person = Person(region)
    random_address = Address(region)
    for i in range(0, int(usersNum)):
        addData = [person.full_name(), country if randint(0, 1) == 1 else random_address.country(), random_address.region(), random_address.city(), random_address.address(), person.telephone()]
        data.append(addData)


    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(buffer, data, extrasaction="ignore")
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    buffer.seek(0)
    dict_reader = csv.DictReader(io.TextIOWrapper(buffer, encoding='utf-8'))
    print(list(dict_reader))



        # print(f"{person.full_name()};   {country if randint(0, 1) == 1 else random_address.country()},"
        #       f" {random_address.region()}, {random_address.city()}, {random_address.address()};   {person.telephone()}")

   # print("All data was generated!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    generate_users(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Создать какой-нибудь промежуточный IO буффер и подсунуть его вместо файла при записи csv. Потом вывести этот буффер.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, поправил код с учетом ваших подсказок, теперь получаю ошибку: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list', ошибка понятна, но с её исправлением возникают вопросы

Comment: Вы в конструктор `DictWriter` в поле `fieldnames ` пихаете значения. Смотрите документацию.